# Map Azure File Service Share with GPO / Login script

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, network-share

I created a Azure File Service shared folder. It comes with a net use script to map the drive. I would like to deploy a logon script that maps the drive automatically. When I try to deploy a User logon script over through a GPO the drive is not mapped. When I do a startup script on the Computer GPO it maps the drive, but it has a big red X on the drive. The O/S is Windows 2012 R2. Is there a best practice to map an Azure File Service Share some one could share? It should be mapped on around 100 servers, so manually doing it is not an option.

Regards,

Shawn Hodgson

Comment: Have you tried to mount the Azure File Share as is described in this Microsoft article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows ? You can create PowerShell script and create basic Scheduled task or share it via GPO

Comment: Are you able to share your script - minus any credentials, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not supported by Microsoft

Open a DOS window as administrator and execute the following:

```
psexec -i -s cmd.exe
```

Within that window execute the following to ensure it reports back you’re the system user

```
whoami
```

Now execute the following

```
cmdkey /add:ACCOUNTNAME.file.core.windows.net /user:ACCOUNTNAME /pass:MYKEY==
```

Next let’s create the file share

```
net use M: \\ACCOUNTNAME.file.core.windows.net\SHAREDFOLDER /u:ACCOUNTNAME 

MYKEY== /persistent:yes
```

if you want to remove this file mount, you have to do it via `PSEXEC`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Azure File Shares for this. They are not a replacement for a traditional file server for a number of reasons, including the fact that it does not support ACLs natively. ACLs can be introduced via Azure File Sync, but that's a different solution that happens to use Azure File Shares on the back end.

If you put the storage account key (the password to the net use command) in a GPO or logon script, it will be readable by every user and computer with permission to process the GPO. That is *really bad*.

Azure File Shares are meant to host things like log files for shared web servers or shared IIS configuration data for applications that are being migrated to the cloud but still have these legacy dependencies. This is not a replacement for a traditional file server for user access.

Some alternatives might be Azure File Sync with IaaS and on-prem replicas, StorSimple appliances, or perhaps a third-party solution like Nasuni, Talon, Panzura, etc.

Comment: This answer was correct in the time it was given. Today you can configure AD authentication for Azure FileShares.